# Both XLOOKUP and INDEX-MATCH aren't returning requested value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup, index-match

I work for a picture frame company, and we are trying to work out which specific parcels that get sent to our customers are accruing surcharges for being Out Of Gauge (overweight, oversized, etc).

We have a table that is sent to us by a courier company, containing various consignment data of which only some of relevant to this. I need to create a second table which should include only the consignment number, and the **total** consignment price, in a singular row. However, I can't seem to match the Out of Gauge rows with their parent rows.

The format for the data that is relevant is as follows:

| Last Parcel Number | Description | Price | Consignment Number | All Parcels in Consignment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | Standard | £ 5.00 | CN001 | 0001 |
| 0003 | Standard | £ 10.00 | CN002 | 0002;0003 |
| 0004 | Standard | £ 5.00 | CN003 | 0004 |
| 0008 | Standard | £ 20.00 | CN004 | 0005;0006;0007;0008 |
| 0010 | Standard | £10.00 | CN005 | 0009;0010 |
| 0002 | Out of Gauge | £ 15.00 |  |  |
| 0009 | Out of Gauge | £ 15.00 |  |  |
| 0010 | Out of Gauge | £ 15.00 |  |  |

I figure I need to pair the Out of Gauge parcel number with a consignment number, and this is what I can't find a solution to. I feel as though I've been overcomplicating things.

Firstly, I'll mention that this new table needs to be refreshable, so all of these functions are enclosed in an IF statement as follows:

```
=IF( E2= "", \<function\>, E2)
```

Result: Correctly displays data when there is already a value in Column4.

**As for when there is no data in Column4:**

Initially I tried an XLOOKUP, and split the contents of Column5 into separate columns with TEXTSPLIT to use as the lookup array:

```
=XLOOKUP( A2, TEXTSPLIT( E2:E5, ";"), D2:D5)
```

Result: All of the Out of Gauge rows returned #N/A.

I also tried the TEXTSPLIT as a standalone function which displayed the result in the columns following on from Column5, in case the issue was that I was trying to TEXTSPLIT within the XLOOKUP, but the only difference is that it returned #VALUE instead.

I then tried INDEX-MATCH, but as far as I can tell it can't be done in that way as the return value is different from the lookup value. Please correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Any possible solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share what the exact output looks like for the posted data? Maybe add a few more critical lines to it to make things clear.

Comment: Since you have the unique consignment numbers in the right hand table, you can simply use SUMIF to get the total values: `=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,TEXTSPLIT(E2, ";"),C:C))` for example, copied down.

Comment: Hi, @VBasic2008. I have added more lines to the table as requested. Apologies if I misunderstood what you were asking for.

Comment: Hi, @Rory. This solution returns a very high and unrelated number. I'm wondering if it is totaling every value in the column, rather than just the matching consignment?

Comment: @Rory, my apologies, I believe I mis-typed your solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @TalynW i have posted some few easy simpler approaches one of it matches with the Rory Sir, could you try any one of them and let me know

Comment: Hi, @MayukhBhattacharya. I tried the first solution of three, and it worked an absolute charm. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @TalynW glad to hear that, it worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` as per the tags posted, and in accordance with the readability and simplicity of the approach, one can use one of the followings, 3 methods shown, two uses `LAMBDA()` helper function called `MAP()` while one other needs to fill down!*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=SUM(SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9,TEXTSPLIT(F2,";")))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H2</kbd>

```
=MAP(F2:F6,LAMBDA(α, SUM((TEXTSPLIT(α,";")=A2:A9)*C2:C9)))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(F2:F6,LAMBDA(x,SUM((TEXTSPLIT(x,";")=A2:A9)*C2:C9)))
```

---

Hope I am not over complicated the solutions. But the basic principles of all the formula solutions posted above uses minimal excel memory consumption so as one can work faster, effortlessly without making the excel engine to slow down.

- In all the above approaches, one can see, i have used `TEXTSPLIT()` as a criteria, what does it do, it splits the cell values in `All Parcels In Consignment` by column wise using the delimiter as `;`
- Once it has been it has been used as a criteria in `SUMIFS()` function.
- Since the `TEXTSPLIT()` will return an array of values, so when using with `SUMIFS()` it will return multiple values for the same, therefore to get the desired output we need to wrap it within a `SUM()` functon.
- Last one using a `LAMBDA()` helper `MAP()` it uses the `LAMBDA()` custom function to iterate through each cells to perform the task it is assigned to and gives the relevant output for each cells.

---

**Addendum:** All the return output can be merged with the `Consignment Number` Columns with `HSTACK()`

---

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Delimited Data

[image: screenshot]

```
=HSTACK(D2:D6,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TOROW(A2:A12),E2:E6)),C2:C12))
```

Comment: Hi, @VBasic2008.
This errored with a "ran out of resources" error. However, I've managed to work around something another helper mentioned earlier in a comment. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Thanks for the edits. FYI I know P.b is the king of `MMULT` but I learned how to use it from your answers. Bye bye `BYROW`! (just kidding).

Comment: `MMULT()` is nice but it is heavy resource, `SUMIFS()` or `XLOOKUP()` with `SUM()` can do the same task here as intended by OP. Simpler approach may be.

Comment: Also it can be made shorter by using `ISERR()` instead of `ISNUMBER()` --> `MMULT(1-ISERR(SEARCH(TOROW(A2:A9),E2:E6)),C2:C9)`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya LOL, now that I've learned how to use it, I'm misusing it. Thanks for the `ISERR` option. Will have to figure it out.

Comment: Sorry `XLOOKUP()` is not a good option here, because i found if there are more than one duplicates in Column A it will return only the first match thus excluding the second hence, `SUMIFS()` or `SUM()`. Can we use `FIND()` in place of `SEARCH()` as well? `=MMULT(1-ISERR(FIND(TOROW(A2:A9),F2:F6)),C2:C9)`